# How send data from Python to Java using Protobuf?

Tags: java, python, tcp, udp, protocol-buffers

Java Client

```
byte[] aReceiveData = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket aReceivePacket = new DatagramPacket(aReceiveData,  aReceiveData.length);
aServerSocket.receive(aReceivePacket);

ByteArrayInputStream aInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(aReceiveData);


Message test = Message.parseDelimitedFrom(aInput);
```

error

```
"Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)."
```

Python Server

```
mensagem = estoque_pb2.Message()
mensagem.type=1
mensagem.id=requestId
mensagem.methodId="test"
mensagem.obfReference="objectRef"
mensagem.arguments=resultado
return mensagem.SerializeToString()

self.udp.sendto(mensagem,self.client)
```

I am not able to send data from python to java using protobuf, thanks any help!

Comment: Yes the port is correct, and I can see that the data is received, the error is at the time of "parseDelimitedFrom"

Answer (score 0):

The received packet can be smaller than 1024 bytes, so one have to create ByteArrayInputStream only on received range of bytes.

The method parseDelimitedFrom intended to parse delimited messages. In fact it reads message length, and then reads message itself. As far, as I understood, your buffer contains only the message. Therefore, you have to use parseFrom method.

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
socket.receive(pkt);

ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkt.getData(), pkt.getOffset(), pkt.getLength());

Message test = Message.parseFrom(input);
```